# Set div height with background without knowing background height

Tags: jquery, html, css, height, masonry

I have tons of same divs. Each has his own background.

```
<div class="grid-item"><div class="grid-con" style="background:url(http://image-goes-here.com/img.jpg);"></div></div>
// etc...
```

I am using jQuery to set properties to background:

```
$(".grid-con").css({"background-size": "100% auto", "background-repeat": "no-repeat", "background-position": "50% 50%"});
```

And css for extra properties:

```
.masonry { float:left; width:950px; margin-top:20px; }
.grid { width:100%;  }
.grid-item { width:217px; margin:0 20px 20px 0; }
.grid-con { width:100%; height:auto; }
```

Everything works fine, if i set fixed height to `.grid-con`.

**Question:**

How to make it work without fixed height? `width:100%` works perfect, but `height:auto` does not. I need to display all backgrounds which needs to fit fixed width with unknown height.

Comment: Why are you using jQuery to set the background properties? Why not just do it in CSS?

Comment: When you say that `height: auto` does not work, what do you mean? What happends, and what would you expect to happend? Please read [MCVE].

Comment: Because if i set jquery css properties to css file, than it does not work. If i set directly to code, than it works as same as jquery method. For example, i have image, which needs to fit fixed width with unknow height, but i need to display automatically calculated height.

Comment: Also, i need to use background method, not a ``<img.. />`` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if the results of [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/1bm0knzp/) are what you're expecting, but here is the code:

```
$('.grid-con[style*=url]').each(function(){
  var $this = $(this),
    img = new Image(),
    src = $this.attr('style').match(/url\(([^)]+)/);
  if ( src && src.length >= 1 ) {
    img.src = src[1];
    $this.height(img.height);
  }
});
```

You could also use the `naturalHeight` of the image if you're not supporting IE8 or older ([ref](http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/naturalwidth-and-naturalheight-in-ie/)).